# Sorting strings by the numbers of characters

Tags: java, string, sorting, numbers, character

I have a problem.
I want to sort Strings from txt file by the numbers of characters in String
For example
Input: 
aaa
a
aa
Output:
a
aa
aaa
I created Collection that contain strings by alphabet & created collection that contain number of String characters,  but i can't understand

How I can sort by the numbers of characters in String

```
public class SortingFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

try{
    File inputFile=new File("c:/a.txt");
    Reader r=new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);

    List <String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
    List <Integer> listLength= new LinkedList<Integer>();

    String line=br.readLine();
    list.add(line);

    while (line!=null){
        line=br.readLine(); 
        list.add(line);
        }

    int arrsize=(list.size())-1;
    System.out.println("line array size= "+arrsize);
    list.remove(arrsize); //delete last element (he is null )

    System.out.println("Before sorting by alphabet: "+list);
    Collections.sort(list);//sorting by alphabet
    System.out.println("After sorting by alphabet: " +list);

    for (int i=0;i!=list.size();i++){ //add string lenght to collection
        String a=list.get(i);
        int aa=a.length();
        listLength.add(aa);
    }
    System.out.println("lineLength:"+listLength);
    Collections.sort(listLength); // sotring by asc
    System.out.println("lineLength2:"+listLength);
    br.close();

}catch (FileNotFoundException e1){
System.out.println("File ''a.txt'' Not Found :(");
e1.printStackTrace();
}


 } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try, with following `Comparator`

```
 Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.length()-o2.length();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Collections.sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) which takes an additional [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) argument.

That allows you to change the way things are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort` has an overloaded method where you can give a `comparator`. Code a comparator where you will compare the length of the strings and return whatever is greater or smaller (depending upon whether you want ascending or descending order). then just invoke your `Collections.sort(myListOfString,myComporator);` and the result would be a list of strings ordered by length.

Answer (score 0):

Pass comparator to your Collection.sort(list,yourSorter) method and use whatever logic you want to use in it.

```
Collections.sort(list, sortAccordingToLength);

 static Comparator<String> sortAccordingToLength= new Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String a, String b) {
      return a.length()-b.length();
  }
});
```

Comment: `a.length() > b.length();` returns a boolean, not an int. Your code does'nt compile. Again a and b are Strings, not int.

Comment: Now check and you can remove your downvote again.

Comment: That's not my downvote but again your code doesn't compile.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate, You should maintain comparator contract. That should return -(value), 0 and +(value). Your compare will always return +(value).

Comment: Agree bro.Hurry makes worry.Now you can check.I wrote my own logic.Just to give him rough idea but now answer is modified according to his requirement

Comment: Now you're not comparing length anymore